# accessing an array within an array returning group data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Currently i am looping through a list of singers and within the array of singers there is an object named songs that each singer sang. I have the for loop setup so i am returning all the singers but i am having trouble looping and returning the songs for each singer.

This is a demo data of what i am trying to return:

```
    singers:{ 
        1{id:1, name: john, songs:[{id:#, name: song1}, {id:#, name:song2}]}
        2{id:2, name: jack, songs:[{id:#, name: song1}, {id:#, name: song2}, {id:#, name: song3}]}
    }
```

This is what i have so i am able to loop to get the list of singers but i want to also return a list of songs for each of the singers:

```
var singer, singerData=[];
for (singer in singers) {
     if (singers.hasOwnProperty(singer)) {
         singerData.push(new viewModel(singers[singer]));
                    }
                }

viewModel = function(singer){
    var self;
        self.singerName = ko.observable(singer.singerName);
        .....
}
```

how can i loop to return the list of songs for each singer so that i can display the data as follows:

```
John: song1, song2
Jack: song1, song2, song3
```

Comment: Do you have any more code? What is a viewModel?

Comment: Post the object that you're iterating over

Answer (score 0):

when you do `for(singer in singers)` `singer` is referring to the index or key in the object you are enumerating over, not the value. You need to do `singers[singer]`. Also do `var singer` to avoid polluting the global scope:

```
for (var i in singers) {
     var singer = singers[i];
     if (singer.hasOwnProperty('songs')) {
         singerData.push(new viewModel(singer));
     }
}
```

also from your question:

> within the array of singers there is an object named songs that each
>   singer sang

I'm assuming you mean that you have an array of objects like this?

```
var singers = [
  { songs: ['song name', 'other song'] }
];
```

Comment: I wanted to loop this within the loop for the singer because the returned results is in a single object that i am using for displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var result = [];
singers = [{id:1, name: "john", songs:[{id:"#", name: "song1"},{id:"#", name:"song2"}]},{id:2, name: "jack", songs:[{id:"#", name: "song1"}, {id:"#", name: "song2"}, {id:"#", name: "song3"}]}];
for( i in singers ) {
    singer = singers[ i ];
    var songs = [];
    for( j in singer.songs ) {
        song = singer.songs[ j ];
        songs.push( song.name );
    }
    result.push( singer.name + ": " + songs.join( ", ") );
}
result = result.join( "\n" );
alert( result );
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/a4a85o8o/](http://JSFIDDLE)